# Use of printf in C++

Tags: c++, coding-style, printf, cout

A search of the site for "printf vs cout" turned up a discussion of the difference between the two, but that isn't what I was looking for. Coming from Python, I'm a huge fan of the way `printf` employs string formatting and I'd rather avoid `cout` if possible.

Is it considered bad practice to ignore `cout` and use `printf` exclusively? What would be the implications of doing this? What are some cases where using `printf` wouldn't be an option?

Comment: If you can use Boost, use Boost.Format.  The C++ iostream library is slow and cumbersome.  The C stdio library is not type safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) You can only use `printf` for fundamental types, and for integers it is really only usable for the "native" types `int`, `long int` etc. Something like `uint32_t` requires rather awkward and cumbersome macros for portable printing. User-defined types are not supported at all.

2) `printf` is not typesafe. That is, the correctness of your code depends on the *value* of the formatting string, and you cannot tell whether your program is well formed from static analysis alone. This is the fundamental weakness of the C typesystem, which "proper" C++ avoids.

That said, `printf` (or perhaps `(v)snprintf`, rather) is usually quite a bit faster than iostreams, so in a high-performance context (e.g. high-frequency logging) it is a very competitive alternative. However, if you just have occasional output operations, you should prefer iostreams, or some other flexible, typesafe, idiomatic C++ method. (And admittedly  iostreams is probably one of the most terrible corners of C++.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it considered bad practice to ignore cout and use printf exclusively?

No, if you prefer to use `printf`, go ahead.

> What would be the implications of doing this?

None. The C++ way would be to use `cout`, because it's supposed to be simpler.

> What are some cases where using printf wouldn't be an option?

I doubt you'll find such cases. If you do, people writing them are too subjective.

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is type-safe. `cout` is an `ostream` and so it has the same interface as other `ostream`s - for instance you can provide new overloads for printing `foo`.

`printf` has format strings which occasionally are better than `cout`'s method of formatting.